# After migrating to Azure, how can I query my organization Active Directory from within the application now hosted in Azure?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am searching around Google about this topic, but I can't find anything that talks about this. We have an ASP.NET WebForms application hosted on premise, and the login authenticate with our Active Directory. I can access the Active Directory outside the office, of course, using a VPN.

However, this application will be migrated to Azure. From Azure, we don't have access to our domain anymore, so we can't query our Active Directory users.

Which options do we have? There's a workaround for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Typically you'd setup Azure AD authentication on the app if you can. That's a rather broad topic, but there are a lot of docs and sample apps in the Microsoft Identity Platform docs.

Comment: That does require you sync your AD to AAD though.

Comment: Do you want to get your azure active directory user list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview) to create an Active Directory domain in the cloud and connect it to your on-premises Active Directory domain. [Azure AD connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity) integrates your on-premises directories with Azure AD. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/) for more details.

With this solution, you need to [setup Azure AD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code) on your app.

Reference:

[Integrate on-premises AD with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/azure-ad).